# how to place multiple markers on Same Address in Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a android app which will retrieve latitude and longitude ,address values from JSON. These values which are retrieved are sent to MapActivity for placing marker on the particular location.

My Problem is, if address is on same Street, it show only one Marker and doesn't show second marker on same street , how i show second marker on googleMap

any help will b appreciated 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to check map by Zooming In?

Comment: yes i check map at Zoom in it show one marker